How do I remotely access one tab of a headless web browser on a headless server? Is this even possible?
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian OS Lite 64-bit.
On it, I will open a headless Chrome window with one tab on a website.
I then want to be able to remotely access and control that one browser tab from preferably my own (head-ful) browser. This tab also needs to stay alive when I disconnect from the RPi, and reconnect to that same tab exactly where I left it.
Is this even possible?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Are you using ssh to the rasp?
If Yes: Try this; do start that session with $ ssh -Y root@rasp ... then start the raspberry pi browser from that shell, be it firefox, chrome or whatever.
Hint: if that works, then the browser is running on the pi, but display is on your local computer.
And yes: A slow connection will of course cause slow screen-updates... No magic provided.

If OP's using SSH - carbonyl  and a screen session feels like a good idea

Raspberry Pi have VNC preinstalled IIRC, and 'simply' connecting to your current graphical sessions via that should do the trick. You 'may' need a dummy HDMI plug, depending on how VNC is set up.
Newer hardware/software builds also have raspberry pi connect, which I believe is VNC with addons, and has a web interface option. You need a Raspberry Pi 4 or better for this.
You can find instructions on setup for a VNC server on the Raspberry Pi Webpage
